# Implementing K-Means algorithm issue

Tags: r

I have tried to implement K-means but something is wrong with the code as I do not get the result.

This is Euclidean distance calculation:

```
euclid <- function(p1, p2) {
   dm <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(p1)[1], ncol=dim(p2)[1])
   for(i in 1:nrow(p2)) {
     dm[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(p1)-p2[i,])^2))
   }
   dm
}
```

This is K-mean algorithm.

```
K_means <- function(dt, c, itr) {

clusterHistory <- vector(itr, mode="list")
centerHistory  <- vector(itr, mode="list")

for(i in 1:itr) {
   distsToCenters <- euclid(dt,c)
   clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
   centers <- apply(dt, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
   # Saving history
   clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
   centerHistory[[i]] <- c
}

list(clusters=clusterHistory, c = centerHistory)
}
```

These are my centers:

```
c <- data.frame(Label = c("A","C","F","M"), X = c(3,2.1,3,5), Y =c(6.1,5.0,5.0,5.0))
```

These are my entire points:

```
dt2 <- data.frame(Label = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"), X = c(3.0,4.0,2.1,4.0,7.0,3.0,6.1,7.0,4.0,3.0,6.2,7.0,5.0,3.5,2.5,3.5,5.5,6.0,0.5,0.8), Y =c(6.1,2.0,5.0,6.0,3.0,5.0,4.0,2.0,1.5,2.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,4.5,6.0,5.5,4.5,1.0,1.5,1.2))
```

this shows result:

```
res <- K_means(dt2[,2:3], c[,2:3], 4)
res
```

I want to put proper labels in proper clusters but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

BTW If assuming this is a self-study question, given that there is a `kmeans` function in R. If so there is a a good course about kmeans on [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/unsupervised-learning-in-r) (1st chapter free)

The problem seems to be with your euclid function, specifically this line

```
dm[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(p1)-p2[i,])^2))
```

This gives the following results for dm

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
 [2,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
 [3,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
 [4,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
 [5,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
 [6,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
 [7,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
 [8,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
 [9,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[10,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
[11,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[12,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
[13,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[14,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
[15,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[16,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
[17,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[18,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
[19,]    0  0.9  0.0  2.0
[20,]    0  1.1  1.1  1.1
```

I replaced this line

```
euclid <- function(p1, p2) {
    dm <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(p1)[1], ncol=dim(p2)[1])
    for(i in 1:nrow(p2)) {
        dm[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(sapply(1:ncol(p1), function(c) {(p1[,c] - p2[i,c])^2})))
    }
    dm
}
```

This uses sapply to iterate over each column.

This gives

```
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
 [1,] 0.000000 1.421267 1.1000000 2.2825424
 [2,] 4.220190 3.551056 3.1622777 3.1622777
 [3,] 1.421267 0.000000 0.9000000 2.9000000
 [4,] 1.004988 2.147091 1.4142136 1.4142136
 [5,] 5.060632 5.292447 4.4721360 2.8284271
 [6,] 1.100000 0.900000 0.0000000 2.0000000
 [7,] 3.744329 4.123106 3.2572995 1.4866069
 [8,] 5.728001 5.745433 5.0000000 3.6055513
 [9,] 4.707441 3.982462 3.6400549 3.6400549
[10,] 4.100000 3.132092 3.0000000 3.6055513
[11,] 5.200961 5.080354 4.3863424 3.2310989
[12,] 5.060632 5.292447 4.4721360 2.8284271
[13,] 2.282542 2.900000 2.0000000 0.0000000
[14,] 1.676305 1.486607 0.7071068 1.5811388
[15,] 0.509902 1.077033 1.1180340 2.6925824
[16,] 0.781025 1.486607 0.7071068 1.5811388
[17,] 2.968164 3.436568 2.5495098 0.7071068
[18,] 5.916925 5.586591 5.0000000 4.1231056
[19,] 5.235456 3.848376 4.3011626 5.7008771
[20,] 5.371220 4.016217 4.3908997 5.6639209
```

EDITED - Labels

To get the cluster labels, I suggest you pass the entire data.frame including labels to your `K_means` function as follows.

Note that I've also changed the code, so that the new centers are being used in subsequent iterations. In your previous code, you were always using the centers which were originally passed.

```
K_means <- function(dt, c, itr) {

clusterHistory <- vector(itr, mode="list")
centerHistory  <- vector(itr, mode="list")

dt_labels <- dt[,1]
dt_data <- dt[,-1]

c_labels <- c[,1]
c_data <- c[,-1]

for(i in 1:itr) {
    distsToCenters <- euclid(dt_data,c_data)
    clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
    c_data <- apply(dt_data, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
    # Saving history
    clusterHistory[[i]] <- data.frame(Label = dt_labels, cluster_label = c_labels[clusters] ,cluster_number = clusters)
    centerHistory[[i]] <- data.frame(Label = c_labels, c_data)

}

list(clusters=clusterHistory, c = centerHistory)
}
```

Changing call to pass entire data.frame. I'm assuming labels are in 1st column.

```
c <- data.frame(Label = c("A","C","F","M"), X = c(3,2.1,3,5), Y =c(6.1,5.0,5.0,5.0)) 
dt2 <- data.frame(Label = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"), X = c(3.0,4.0,2.1,4.0,7.0,3.0,6.1,7.0,4.0,3.0,6.2,7.0,5.0,3.5,2.5,3.5,5.5,6.0,0.5,0.8), Y =c(6.1,2.0,5.0,6.0,3.0,5.0,4.0,2.0,1.5,2.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,4.5,6.0,5.5,4.5,1.0,1.5,1.2)) 

res <- K_means(dt2, c, 4)
res
```

This gives the following results

```
$clusters
$clusters[[1]]
   Label cluster_label cluster_number
1      A             A              1
2      B             F              3
3      C             C              2
4      D             A              1
5      E             M              4
6      F             F              3
7      G             M              4
8      H             M              4
9      I             F              3
10     J             F              3
11     K             M              4
12     L             M              4
13     M             M              4
14     N             F              3
15     O             A              1
16     P             F              3
17     Q             M              4
18     R             M              4
19     S             C              2
20     T             C              2

$clusters[[2]]
   Label cluster_label cluster_number
1      A             A              1
2      B             F              3
3      C             A              1
4      D             A              1
5      E             M              4
6      F             A              1
7      G             M              4
8      H             M              4
9      I             F              3
10     J             F              3
11     K             M              4
12     L             M              4
13     M             A              1
14     N             F              3
15     O             A              1
16     P             A              1
17     Q             M              4
18     R             M              4
19     S             C              2
20     T             C              2

$clusters[[3]]
   Label cluster_label cluster_number
1      A             A              1
2      B             F              3
3      C             A              1
4      D             A              1
5      E             M              4
6      F             A              1
7      G             M              4
8      H             M              4
9      I             F              3
10     J             F              3
11     K             M              4
12     L             M              4
13     M             A              1
14     N             A              1
15     O             A              1
16     P             A              1
17     Q             M              4
18     R             M              4
19     S             C              2
20     T             C              2

$clusters[[4]]
   Label cluster_label cluster_number
1      A             A              1
2      B             F              3
3      C             A              1
4      D             A              1
5      E             M              4
6      F             A              1
7      G             M              4
8      H             M              4
9      I             F              3
10     J             F              3
11     K             M              4
12     L             M              4
13     M             A              1
14     N             A              1
15     O             A              1
16     P             A              1
17     Q             M              4
18     R             M              4
19     S             C              2
20     T             C              2


$c
$c[[1]]
  Label        X        Y
1     A 3.166667 6.033333
2     C 1.133333 2.566667
3     F 3.500000 3.416667
4     M 6.225000 3.062500

$c[[2]]
  Label     X        Y
1     A 3.300 5.514286
2     C 0.650 1.350000
3     F 3.625 2.500000
4     M 6.400 2.785714

$c[[3]]
  Label        X        Y
1     A 3.325000 5.387500
2     C 0.650000 1.350000
3     F 3.666667 1.833333
4     M 6.400000 2.785714

$c[[4]]
  Label        X        Y
1     A 3.325000 5.387500
2     C 0.650000 1.350000
3     F 3.666667 1.833333
4     M 6.400000 2.785714
```